Declare function which takes Vue component and props
I want to declare a function which will accept a Vue component, and an object containing props which can be used to create an instance of that component.
The intention is to use these values later to display a component like so:
<component :is="component" v-bind="props" />

I have tried the following:
function addEntry<T extends Component<P>, P>(
    component: T,
    props: ExtractPublicPropTypes<P>,
)

But in usage, it appears P is not infered - props is typed as ExtractPublicPropTypes<unknown>, which evaluates to { [x: string]: unknown; } and any object is allowed as the props parameter, without requiring any specific fields.
I have also tried typing it using DeclareComponent<P> and variations, but I get errors similar to the following. ({ data: string } is the props definition of the used component)
Property 'data' is missing in type 'LooseRequired<{}>' but required in type 'LooseRequired<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToOption<{ data: string; }>>> & {}>'

